# Getting google home weather unit setting in the custom actions fulfillment code

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

We are creating a custom google action. The fulfillment code is in python.

We need google home weather unit in the code.
How to get the google home  weather unit setting in the python code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such capability for a developer to pull this information about a user.